# R CMD BATCH - output in terminal

Tags: r, batch-processing

Just learning R and I thought it would be great to use it in batch mode in the unix terminal instead of writing in the R terminal.

So I decided to write test.r

```
    x <- 2
    print(x)
```

then in terminal I did

```
    R CMD BATCH test.r
```

it runs, But outputs a test.r.Rout file. I can get it to output to say a text file by running R CMD BATCH test.r out.txt.

Question is, is it possible to print the output to the terminal?

Comment: You really should go back and accept answers to your previous questions.

Comment: good call matthew, wasn't aware of that feature

Comment: Rscript test.r was the solution, thanks Sebastian-C

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sebastian-C posted:

```
    Rscript test.r
```

This worked in the terminal and produced the desired output

Thanks Sebastian-C

Comment: You can accept your own answer, this signals that the question was answered.

Comment: apparently I need to wait 2 days... it says.

Comment: Hmm, I seem to remember that this was 2 hours, but maybe this does not hold for self accepting answers.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat late reaction, but the other day I was looking for the answer to exactly the question Blakedallen posted. Here's my solution:

```
mkfifo fifo   # create a named pipe
cat fifo &    # show everything to the terminal 
              # (or do 'cat fifo' in another terminal)
R CMD BATCH input # 'input' contains your R commands
```

Works like a charm :-)

The 'fifo' named pipe can be used again for any future R CMD BATCH commands
you may want to execute. After the 'R CMD BATCH' command the 'cat' command also ends.