# R batch mode: How to see output/error of R on console screen?

Tags: r, batch-processing

While running R code in batch mode i need messages/errors/logs from R code to be shown on console screen instead of .Rout file.

I tried all the posts(links copied below) from stack overflow and **none of them are showing me desired output.**

1. [running-r-in-batch-mode-print-to-screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263741/unable-to-run-r-script-through-bat-files-in-windows-server?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [unable-to-run-r-script-through-bat-files-in-windows-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263741/unable-to-run-r-script-through-bat-files-in-windows-server?noredirect=1&lq=1)
3. [r-cmd-batch-output-in-terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432637/r-cmd-batch-output-in-terminal)

batch code: i tried with tty0 as well.

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH --slave "Test.R" /dev/tty
```

Test.R code

```
print(1:10)
```

It will be very helpful if some has can help me in showing the correct way of writing the code to show the output in console screen.And i am working on windows environment.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of running R in batch mode that you don't have a person there to see what is happening?  Batch mode is more for for automated analyses.  If you want to see the output, look in the log file or run R interactively.

Comment: @RichieCotton my purpose of running R code in batch is to make 3rd person not to open R/Rstudio. And i need to see intermediate results so i want that output to be in console screen.

Comment: I think you want Rscript, not R CMD BATCH

Comment: @shayaa i am not familiar with format of .bat files. Can you please give me some example?

Comment: Might want to read [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412911/r-exe-rcmd-exe-rscript-exe-and-rterm-exe-whats-the-difference)

Comment: Thanks @shayaa. It worked

Comment: How about you write your solution up for posterity, unless you wish to ask @abhiieor to edit his post with the full solution. Neither you nor I have the requisite rep to edit another's post.

Comment: @shayaa posted solution. Please upvote and mark it as solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect the log that you want to print using `stdout` or `stderr`. Sample way to do that will be:

```
write("Hello World!!", stderr())
```

Here I am redirecting "Hello World!!" to `stderr`. If you use `stdout()` instead of `stderr()` in code snippet above then ideally it should write log to `stdout`. However I have seen some issues when trying to write into `stdout`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its not working, it still showing output in .Rout file. I intentionally plugged a undeclared variable `ss` in the code so that it can throw error in console, but it has shown error in .Rout file.`write("Hello World!!",ss, stderr())`

Comment: @Shayaa is correct. Please run your R script with "Rscript <scriptName>" and you will be able to write as suggested above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply .It worked with the help of `Stdout()`

Answer (score 1):

I found out solution to my own question with the help of @shayaa and @abhiieor.

In case if some one needs to see their output in console they are suppose to use Rscript instead of R CMD BATCH in executable .bat file.

batch code:

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\Rscript.exe" Test.R
pause
```

Test.R code

`print("-Hello World!!",stdout())`

In above code `stdout()` will redirect output to console.