# R - How to display progress when executing scripts via Command Prompt

Tags: r, scheduled-tasks, command-prompt

I've been using the command prompt to schedule and execute R scripts. However, the prompt always displays an empty screen when executing scripts. Is it possible to display text of the script running?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38549285/4996248

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for.